# Explanation of requirement from inputs to GPU computations having complex results

Tags: matlab, memory-management, gpgpu, complex-numbers, gpuarray

Consider this line of code:

```
gpuArray(-1)^0.5;
```

Which results in:

```
ans =
   0.0000 + 1.0000i
```

Now consider the following line of code:

```
gpuArray(-1).^0.5;
```

Which results in:

```
Error using  .^ 
POWER: needs to return a complex result, but this is not supported for real input X and Y on 
the GPU. Use POWER(COMPLEX(X), COMPLEX(Y,0)) instead.
```

The problem clearly has something to do with a `double -> complex double` conversion on the GPU, which is not allowed. Indeed, when I apply the workaround (which is also mentioned in the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-matlab-functions-on-a-gpu.html#bsp72oi-1)) it solves the problem - but I don't understand why.

Would anybody shed some light on this? Is this some limitation of VRAM? Of the specific card I'm using (mine is GTX 660, having a CC of 3.0)? Of the MATLAB implementation (I'm using R2018b)? Of the OS?

Comment: Given that the first operation works, I would guess it is in the implementation of `gpuArray.power`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods of `gpuArray` that behave this way, and the reason is simple: performance.

It is perfectly possible to write an implementation of e.g. `sqrt` that behaves on the GPU the same way that MATLAB's CPU implementation works (i.e. compute a real result unless a complex result is required - in which case, return a complex result). Part of the work is already performed - otherwise the `gpuArray` method wouldn't know when to throw an error. However, the expensive part is then re-allocating the (complex) output, and performing the operation again.

There are other slight noticeable quirks relating to `gpuArray` and complex numbers - on the GPU, all-zero imaginary parts are not removed when the MATLAB CPU implementation would remove them. For example:

```
>> a = [1i, 2]; gA = gpuArray(a);
>> [isreal(a(2)), isreal(gA(2))]
ans =
  1×2 logical array
   1   0
```

(Remembering of course that MATLAB's `isreal` function tells you about *storage*, not *values*).

**EDIT:** Just realised that there's a [specific doc reference](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-matlab-functions-on-a-gpu.html#bsp72oi-1) for the functions of `gpuArray` that behave this way.